# Is it possible to run some script on BeagleBone Black while linux is booting?

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I want to show some kind of loading screen on LCD display while beagleBone is booting linux.

Is it possible?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Plymouth is how Fedora and Ubuntu splash screens work.

According to Arch Linux, [Plymouth requires Kernel Mode Setting or an applicable buffer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plymouth), so assuming that you have the DRM modesetting capabilities (see Plymouth link below) you could evaluate cross-compiling from source.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/